# Derivative of $\ f (y/x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, partial-derivative

I had a little argument with a friend about this. Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that
$$g(x,y,z) =xy \ f \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) -z $$

Then, is it mathematically correct to write (I think this is completely ok)
$$\nabla g = \left[ y \ f \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) + xy \ f' \left( \frac{y}{x} \right) \left( - \frac{y}{x^2} \right) \right] \hat i + [ \cdots ] \ \hat j - \hat k \tag{1}$$

My friend claims that since $f$ depends on two variables, I cannot just simply write $f'$, and she says that I should have defined $u = \frac{y}{x}$ so that $f'(u)$ would be meaningful.

i.e. she says that the only way to write this gradient is 
$$\nabla g = \left[ y \ f (u) + xy \ f' (u) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right] \hat i + [ \cdots ] \ \hat j - \hat k \tag{2}$$

I know the way she does in (2) is also true, but does my notation (1) have a problem?

Comment: I removed the scaled parentheses from the title since the page looks cluttered when loading with this in the title.

Comment: She is wrong in saying that you can't write $f'$ and in saying that you 'should define $u$'. You can easily do without defining $u$. Also tell her to replace $f$ by $\sin$. Really, you can't write $\sin'$? She's mistaking $f\circ u$ with $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you are both right. It is clear that here $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and as such $f'$ is perfectly legitimate. You consider the map (with an appropriate domain of definition)
$$
\tilde{f}\colon (x,y) \mapsto f(y/x),
$$
and *this* is a function of two variables. But
$$
\partial_1\tilde{f}(x,y)=xf'(y/x)
$$
is a good piece of notation.
Your friend is essentially factorizing $\tilde{f}$ as
$$
(x,y) \mapsto y/x=u \mapsto f(y/x),
$$
but I can't see any real difference between your approaches.